# NMDA receptor mediated plasticity figure reference

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neurotransmitter, neuroplasticity

Because most of this research is over a decade old, finding a paper with a figure that clearly shows that (neuronal) synaptic plasticity (such as long-term potentiation/LTP) is NMDA receptor mediated has proven very difficult for me.

Is there a good reference for this?

Comment: Not all types of LTP are NMDA-receptor mediated. To find a paper that shows a form that is, I would suggest searching terms like LTP and NMDA antagonist or blockade or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the "Boss references" (nearly 11000 citations right now) for this is Bliss and Collingridge, *A Synaptic Model of Memory: Long-Term Potentiation in the Hippocampus*.
Being from 1993, it has references to some of the earlier work in this field (if that's what you're looking for). 
It notes the different forms of NMDA-dependent and independent plasticity.
Another paper, also from 1993, on this topic is Malenka and Nicoll, *NMDA-receptor-dependent synaptic plasticity: multiple forms and mechanisms*

Some nice reviews with more recent work, focusing on the NMDAR itself include:

- Paoletti et al, *NMDA  Receptor Subunit Diversity:
  Impact on Receptor Properties,
  Synaptic Plasticity and Disease*
- Lau & Zukin, *NMDA Receptor Trafficking in Synaptic Plasticity and Neuropsychiatric Disorders*

and their references.

Comment: would you directly recommend a figure out of these papers?

Comment: @user2305193 What exactly are you hoping for the figure to show?

Comment: the NMDA receptor dependency within LTP

Comment: @user2305193 How about Malenka and Nicoll's figure 1 (which is actually taken from one of their references)? That shows its dependency experimentally. If you're talking about conceptually, maybe box 2 in Bliss and Collingridge?